# vscodeのインライン入力の予測変換の場所が見づらい

Tags: macos, vscode

OS:macOS highe sierra 10.13.6
vscode バージョン1.25.1 (1.25.1)
入力エンジン？：google日本語入力

vscodeで日本語入力をするさいに
こんな感じで予測変換が被ります．
[image]
↑８行目に"あああ”と入力した際の画面
予測変換をしないようにすること以外での解決方法を知っている人いればお願いします．